# Insert "Download on iTunes" button in app

Tags: ios, button, itunes

My app shows the title of a certain song and I would like to insert a "Download on iTunes" button that open iTunes on my iPhone pointing to my song.
I've retrieved the correct iTunes url, using the [iTunes Link Maker](http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker?)
but I've two questions for you.

- In which way can I add this button to my UIView? Do I have to insert a standard button? Which method do I have to call?
- Is it possible to dynamically compose the iTunes url?

---

I've tried to implement the following method:

```
- (void) openItunes
{
    NSString *iTunesLink = selectedAlbum.itunesLink;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
}
```

with `iTunesLink` like `itms://itunes.apple.com/it/album/...`. If I launch this url with Safari, iTunes is automatically opened focusing on the right song. But if I invoke the `openItunes` method from simulator or iPad Touch nothing happens.
Any ideas?

Regards, yassa

Comment: Hello, any suggestions on the issue? I'm still stuck on this! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally this worked for me:

```
- (IBAction)buyAlbum:(id)sender
{
    NSString* url = @"itms://itunes.apple.com/it/album/love-life-lamore-e-la-vita/id298792107?uo=4";

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url ]];
}
```

yassa