# What are my options for linking to a podcast from my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

Using the [iTunes Link Maker](http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker?), and with reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8709719/11575), I've created a test app that can launch the iTunes app and list the episodes of a given podcast:

```
NSString *address = @"itms://itunes.apple.com/<country code>/podcast/<podcast name>/id<numeric ID>?uo=4";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:address]];
```

But what else is possible?

1. From my app, can I launch the iTunes app to start downloading a particular podcast episode?
2. From my app, can I launch the iTunes app to start streaming a particular podcast episode?
3. From my app, can I launch Apple's new [Podcasts app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/podcasts/id525463029?mt=8) if the user has it installed?

Answer (score 2):

[3]. Yes, you can. Just change

```
itms://[url]
```

To any of these forms:

```
itms-pcast://[url]
itms-pcasts://[url]
itms-podcast://[url]
itms-podcasts://[url]
```

Comment: Aha. Thanks for that! It does indeed launch the Podcasts app. After that though, it goes wrong. It asks whether I'd like to subscribe to the podcast and then complains that the link doesn't describe a valid podcast. Do you know where I can find documentation for this? I'd expect it to be covered at http://www.apple.com/itunes/linkmaker/faq/ but it isn't mentioned. I guess it's all pretty new.